Oscillator phase noise effects
The usual complications of phase noise in a practical system that I see mentioned are:

If the RF input of a mixer contains an interferer close to the desired signal, then the interferer mixes with the LO signal and its phase noise skirts which can overlap with the desired IF signal.
Phase noise also corresponds to random jitter which, if the oscillator is used to control digital logic, leads to reduced timing margins.

Supposing that an oscillator isn't going to be used to control any digital logic (so 2 is irrelevant), and the RF input to a mixer is assumed to be very clean and free of interferers, is phase noise irrelevant? Or are there other considerations?

You are using an oscillator to drive LO of a mixer to downconvert an RF signal to IF and asking whether the phase noise of the oscillator matters. The phase noise in LO will add to the phase noise of the downconverted signal in IF. So the whether it matters or not depends on what kind of phase noise requirements you have for IF. For example, phase noise will make it harder to demodulate signals.
